# Embed Interactive Excel Spreadsheets Into Website

Tags: html, excel, tinymce, wysiwyg, spreadsheet

Been searching online for best ways to embed interactive spreadsheets into my website. My users primarily use MS Excel and it would be great if they could post their spreadsheets into our CMS with the following features (maybe I'm asking for too much!):

- Has a read-only mode.
- Easy to import.
- Formats and links are kept.
- Has Excel functionality such as sorting, filtering, etc.
- Supports Excel plugins.
- Can embed into a WYSIWYG editor, especially TinyMCE.

I keep coming across Zoho Sheets, but was wondering if the wise members of StackOverflow have come across anything better.

Cheers!

Comment: You may be able to load actual Excel via ActiveX or something.  This isn't something you are going to be able to easily use with TinyMCE though.  You also might consider embedding with Google Docs.

Comment: Did you have a look at MS SHarepoint? It does not offer everything your are asking for but it integrates good with MS Office/Excel

Comment: Thanks @Brad and @cmmi. Unfortunately, was hoping for an easy, free and customizable solution, kind of like TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a JQuery solution?  It's free and opensource.  Check out: http://visop-dev.com/Project+jQuery.sheet

Comment: thanks for the link. That's a pretty interesting idea, although it seems like JQuery.sheet is still very much in a nascent stage [very slow, not UI friendly, some Demos don't seem to work]. Further, unfortunately, we have to use MS Excel in our office.